# xpath not allowing id and name having same value

Tags: php, xpath

I have some html like this

```
<tr id="start_5672297" data-start-id="5672297" data-start-no="" class="start">
...
  <td class="club">
    <div>
      <a href="xxxx" name="start_5672297">xxxx</a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

A `$doc = new DOMDocument(); $doc->loadHTML($text);` 
gives the error

> ID start_5672297 already defined

It seems like loadHTML does not distinguish between `ID=` and `name=`

If I "preprocess" the $text with `$text = str_replace('name="start', 'name="xstart', $text );` I can parse the text fine;

Am I missing something obvious or is it a bug?

Comment: In a way, I can see why this is an issue. If an HTML document was loaded and asked to display the `#start_5672297` fragment, how would it choose which one to show

Comment: Duplicate name are allowed in html

For instance
`<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>`

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate post, only anchor (`<a>`) `name` attributes share namespace with `id` attributes